# Why Windows 10 start menu settings are not saved but instead they revert back immedietly?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, default-settings

I just got Lenovo Y520. Spent some time updating Windows 10 Home edition that ships with it, installing few apps (VLC, XAMPP, VMWare..etc). At some point when I change any setting regarding start menu, it get back to previous state immediately once I'm out of the window.

Here is screenshot of the settings I'm talking about

[image: Start settings example]

According to this screenshot, say I enabled "**Show more tiles on Start**" then I click on "**Themes**" from left panel and go back to "**Start**" again, I find the option "**Show more tiles on Start**" *disabled* as if I never enabled it !!!

What could possibly cause this ?
What would be possible solution ?

Note that

- I searched a lot and tried removing touchpad driver completely which is Elan not Synaptics like mentioned in most online locations.
- Also tried changing settings in safe mode, the result was that the settings window closes completely once I click on "Themes" after enabling "Show more tiles on Start".
- I ran the command `sfc /scannow` in safe mode and without safe mode. no success so far.
- Created another account as administrator then tested the settings on that account, found it working as expected. So I tried a solution mentioned on some online locations that involves copying `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu Places` using the old account to make a backup then going to the new account and copy the backed up folder content (what's inside Start Menu Places) to completely new created folder called `Start Menu Places` that should be in same location. No success either.

Comment: Run `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth` to see if it finds anything. If nothing is found, and as your profile seems to have been corrupted, you might stay with the new one and copy your files to it from `C:\Users\`.

Comment: This might be a long shot, but is Windows activated?

Comment: I ended up creating and using that new user profile. Thanks for help fellas

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `DISM` commands to verify whether corruption exists without performing
any repairs:

```
dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
```

If `DISM` finds a problem, run these commands to fix:

```
dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
sfc /scannow
```

If nothing is found, and as your profile seems to have been corrupted,
you might stay with the new profile, and may copy your files to it from `C:\Users`.

Comment: I'll get to testing this, this afternoon.

Comment: Too late for your bounty.